# How to read logical data with header from file

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to read the following table

```
#logical.table
      col_a col_b
row_a TRUE  FALSE
row_b FALSE TRUE
```

the resulting object in R should have the column and row names from the file(at least one of them) and logical columns and rows

I tried:

- `matrix(ncol=2, byrow=T, scan(file = 'logical.table', what=TRUE, skip=1))` but I miss the col/row-names.
- deleting rownames,  `w<-read.table(file='logical.table',   colClasses = "logical", header=T)` but `is.logical(w[1])` and `is.logical(w[1,])` return False

**Solution**
As Derwin McGeary wrote: `x <- read.table(file="logical.table")` works just fine.
For logical columns I use `x[,col]` and for logical rows I ended up with `t(x)[,row]`.

Comment: Doesnt just `read.table(file='logical.table', header=T)` work?

Comment: Try `is.logical(w[,1])` or `is.logical(w[[1]])` otherwise its a data.frame

Comment: @user20650 `read.table` works. I was confused because `is.logical(w[1,])` would return false, but `is.logical(t(w)[,1])`seems to do the trick

Comment: yes, ive made the same mistake... if you look at `class(w[1,])` or `class(w[1])` (or `str`)you will see it is a dataframe, hence `is.logical` is false. You need to index the column os use double square brackets (as above comment) to convert the column to a vector. For the rows you could use `is.logical(unlist(w[1,]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function `read.table` is smart enough to read that file and give the appropriate row and column names.

`x <- read.table(file="logical.table")
str(x)`

I cut and pasted your example including the line `#logical.table` and it still worked.